# Converting 360 Panorama image to VR-View compatible image

Tags: android, google-api, google-cardboard, virtual-reality, 360-virtual-reality

I would like to convert the 360 degree Panorama image captured from Cardboard camera programmatically into an image that can be displayed in vr-view in android.
This is the website that I used to handle the conversion:
http://storage.googleapis.com/cardboard-camera-converter/index.html
as suggested [here](https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview)

This is my current work flow:

1. Capture image  through Cardboard camera
2. Upload to website for conversion
3. Download stereo 360 format
4. Display in android app.

I want to automate this process such that I would not have to manually drop an image into the website for conversion and then download it. Is there an API I can hit for this functionality? Or any additions in code that would help me achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: same question here. @Sup Did u find an answer?

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: I did not find a solution, it was for a hackathon, I did not pursue it after that.